# Trigger on Attachment object not working in lightning experience

Tags: salesforce

I have created a trigger on attachment object i am performing some operations in it ( on attachment after insert ). The trigger is getting execute successfully in salesforce classic mode but when i change mode from classic to lightning the trigger is not going to execute.

The triggers on other objects are running successfully in lightning. I am facing issue with this attachment object only.

Is there any solution to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While uploading a file in classic mode "Attachment" trigger gets executed and in Lightning Mode "ContentDocumentLink" Trigger gets executed.

Try this for Lightning Mode:

```
trigger ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (before insert, after Insert) {

     if(Trigger.isAfter) {

        //enter code here
       }
}
```

Hope this will help!